# Astropy cannot parse inches

Tags: python, units-of-measurement, astropy

I am trying to convert `inches` to `mm` with **astropy**.
In input I have unit as string ("inch","mm"). I create for it example function:

```
    def astro_conv(self, amount: float, fromm: str, to: str) -> float:
         u_from = u.Unit(fromm)
         u_to = u.Unit(to)
         return u_from.to(u_to, amount)
```

I got message:`{ValueError}'inch' did not parse as unit: At col 0, inch is not a valid unit.` I have check documentation and `inch` should be available: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the docs ""This package defines colloquially used Imperial units. They are available in the astropy.units.imperial namespace, but not in the top-level astropy.units namespace, To include them: `import astropy.units as u,
 u.imperial.enable() `

Comment: Yes, You are right! I was blind :)

Answer (score 1):

[Per the docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/#module-astropy.units.imperial), Astropy does not include imperial units defined by default.  I think this is in part to reduce the default units namespace and the overhead involved in creating and searching it, and imperial units get sacrificed in this case since they are less used in astronomy for the most part:

> This package defines colloquially used Imperial units. They are available in the astropy.units.imperial namespace, but not in the top-level astropy.units namespace, e.g.:

```
>>> import astropy.units as u
>>> mph = u.imperial.mile / u.hour
>>> mph
Unit("mi / h")
```

> To include them in compose and the results of `find_equivalent_units`, do:

```
>>> import astropy.units as u
>>> u.imperial.enable()
```